# MongoDB: Query to get custom field layout

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am pretty new at MongoDB. I am trying to get values from a specific object array field that is in all of the documents in my collection and put all those values into one array.

```
 Cars.aggregate([ { $project : { 'carCrashes.location' : 1 , _id: 0 } } ] )
```

My Cars document schema is:

```
ownerName: string;
clientCategory: string;
carCrashes: [{  //////////this can be empty in some documents//////////
            dateOfCrash: Date,
            location: string,
            other...
           }]
other...
```

And when using aggregate the way i did i get

```
[
  {
     "carCrashes": [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {
            "location": "Tokyo, Japan"
        },
        {
            "location": "Moskow, Russia"
        },
        {
            "location": "London, UK"
        }
   ]
},
{
    "carCrashes": []
},
{
    "carCrashes": []
},
{
    "carCrashes": [
        {},
        {},
        {
            "location": "New York, USA"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I want it to be like this if possible

```
[
  {
     "location": "Tokyo, Japan"
  },
  {
     "location": "Moskow, Russia"
  },
  {
     "location": "London, UK"
  },
  {
     "location": "New York, USA"   //from another document
  }
]
```

So I want to grab all of the "location" elements I get and put them in array like this so that it is easier for me to sort them and use this data. Also how could I sort them in ASC order?
Any help is good. Thank's in advance

Comment: Try this `Cars.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$carCrashes"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      carCrashes: {
        $push: {
          location: "$carCrashes.location"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query.

`$match` to process car documents where atleast one `carCrashes`array element has location field.

`$filter` to drop all the array elements where location is not present.

`$unwind` + `$sort` the locations.

`$replaceRoot` to promote the location sub document to the top.

```
Cars.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"carCrashes.location":{"$exists":true}}},
  {"$project":{
    "carCrashes":{
      "$filter":{
        "input":"$carCrashes",
        "cond":{"$gt":["$$this.location",0]}
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$carCrashes"},
  {"$sort":{"carCrashes.location":1}}
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$carCrashes"}}
])
```